# My Index table doesn't line up

Tags: c++

> i would like to print the index table like the one i have here
>       but it isn't lining up correctly. I think i am missing an endl;
>       thank you in advance. They would not let me post this question without alot more context so i am typing this to see if this may work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{


cout << "Wind Chill Table" << endl;         //Produces the table
cout << "Speed  Temperature  T " << endl;   //Produces the table
cout << "MPH";                              //Produces the table



for (int temp = 45; temp >= -10; temp -= 5) // Generate temp 45 to -10
{
cout << setw(5)<< temp ;
}

cout << endl;


for (int count = 0; count <= 62; count++)   // generate the lines "------"
{
cout << "-" ;   
}
cout << endl;

for(int speed = 5; speed <=50; speed+=5)    // generate the speed 5 to 50
{
cout << setw(5)<< speed <<"|" << endl;
for (int temp = 45; temp >=-10; temp -= 5 )
{

cout << setw(5)<<windchill( speed,temp);// calling the function windchill
}
cout << endl;
} 

return 0;
}




int windchill(int s, int t)// function to calculate the wind chill
{

int windChillFactor = int(round(35.74 + 0.6215 * 
t - 35.75 * pow(s, 0.15) + 
0.4275 * t * pow(s, 0.16)));    //Formula for wind chill 

return windChillFactor;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
int main()
{


    cout << "Wind Chill Table" << endl;         //Produces the table
    cout << "Speed  Temperature  T " << endl;   //Produces the table
    cout << "MPH"<< endl;                       //Produces the table



    cout << setw(6) <<" "; /*!!! change !!!*/
    for (int temp = 45; temp >= -10; temp -= 5) // Generate temp 45 to -10
    {
        cout << setw(5)<< temp ;
    }

    cout << endl;


    for (int count = 0; count <= 62; count++)   // generate the lines "------"
    {
        cout << "-" ;   
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int speed = 5; speed <=50; speed+=5)    // generate the speed 5 to 50
    {
        cout << setw(5)<< speed <<"|" /*<< endl*/; /*!!! change !!!*/
        for (int temp = 45; temp >=-10; temp -= 5 )
        {
            cout << setw(5)<<windchill( speed,temp);// calling the function windchill
        }
        cout << endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Wind Chill Table
Speed  Temperature  T
MPH
         45   40   35   30   25   20   15   10    5    0   -5  -10
---------------------------------------------------------------
    5|   43   37   31   25   20   14    8    2   -4  -10  -16  -22
   10|   41   35   29   22   16   10    4   -2   -9  -15  -21  -27
   15|   40   33   27   21   14    8    1   -5  -12  -18  -24  -31
   20|   39   32   26   19   13    6   -1   -7  -14  -20  -27  -33
   25|   38   31   25   18   11    5   -2   -9  -16  -22  -29  -36
   30|   37   31   24   17   10    3   -3  -10  -17  -24  -31  -37
   35|   37   30   23   16    9    2   -5  -11  -18  -25  -32  -39
   40|   36   29   22   15    8    1   -6  -13  -19  -26  -33  -40
   45|   36   29   22   15    8    1   -6  -13  -21  -28  -35  -42
   50|   35   28   21   14    7    0   -7  -14  -21  -29  -36  -43
```